# Android Exception End of input at character 0 because of ñ character

Tags: android, mysqli

I am trying to read a mysql database and when I add the character ñ, this code throws org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "UTF-8"), 500);
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");


                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
                Log.e("Here", "the string is"+json); //Nothing appear
                    try {

                        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("JSON Parser Error", "" + e.toString());
                    }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(" Buffer error", "" + e.toString());
            }
```

In BufferedReader I've tried with the charsets UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1. In the database I've tried with utf8_bin and latin1. I think the problem could also be in the PHP which is this

```
mysqli_select_db($conn,$DBName) or die("Unable to select la database    $DBName");

$response = array();

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *FROM $table") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
$response["post"] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $product = array();
    $product["User"] = $row["User"];
    $product["Date"] = $row["Date"];
    $product["Time"] = $row["Time"];
    $product["About"] = $row["About"];
    $product["PostText"] = $row["PostText"];
    $product["Score"] = $row["Score"];
```

Any idea where is the problem? thank you

Comment: its means you are not getting any data from your back end Api. Try to print the response on the logcat using log.d.